# UWP show progress bar while webview is downloading

Tags: c#, webview, uwp

I would like to show the progress of an `UWP Web View` while is downloading the content. This is what I have done:

main_page.xaml:

```
<Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="20"
Foreground="#FF000000">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="_grid" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="_contentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <WebView 
            x:Name="webView" 
            Margin="0,0,0,0" 
            Grid.Row="1" 
            />

        <ProgressBar x:Name="_progressBar" Margin="10,10,0,754" IsIndeterminate="False" Visibility="Collapsed"/>

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

In the NavigationStarting event I show the progress bar:

```
 private async void WebView_Navigation_Starting(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
    {
        //show progress bar
        _progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
.......
}
```

I hide it when the content is loaded :

```
 void WebView_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //show progress bar
        _progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

And here is where I want to update the value of the progress in the progress bar. But how can I get the actual percentage value for the web view content loaded??

```
 void WebView_Content_Loading(WebView sender, WebViewContentLoadingEventArgs args) {
        webView.SetValue(???);
    }
```

Comment: Did you check what information the WebViewContentLoadingEventArgs contains?

Comment: I did it and in this event I dont have the information I want, maybe is the wrong event??

Comment: I might be wrong but you could try to update the progressbar in the loading event say +1 everytime the loading event is triggered, and in the navigation completed (or loaded I don't remember) event update the progressbar to 100% and hide it. So it won't really indicate the exact percentage of completness but simulate a similar behavior.

Comment: I'm afraid this can not be done for now, the content loading event args only contains the uri information, I think you may submit a request to add this new features for developing through the Windows Feedback tool.